# How to Declare local functions in the window in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I create a local function wf_remember for remembering the customer name.can any one help me how to declare that function in window?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you just need to declare an instance variable that holds the customername

```
String is_customername
```

Then in your function you set `is_customername = the_customername` to be remembered.

How to declare a function? 
To add a function you go to the function list and choose Add from the context menu.